# httpd - CPU utilization 100% - Mysql server remote location

Tags: mysql, apache

Having databases one on local and other is on remote server location.
Framework - cakePHP
Mysql: 5.1.71 - "remote location"
PHP Version 5.5.14

Now while using the local mysql database, the CPU utilization is normal for httpd request while checking using TOP command.

However while I am using the remote server database. the CPU utilization is going upto 70 % or sometime 100% for visiting same page.

Following are the few main settings for php.ini and httpd.conf files

php.ini

```
memory_limit = 128M
max_input_time = 60
post_max_size = 8M
```

httpd.conf

```
<IfModule prefork.c>
StartServers       8
MinSpareServers    5
MaxSpareServers   20
ServerLimit      256
MaxClients       256
MaxRequestsPerChild  4000
</IfModule>

<IfModule worker.c>
StartServers         4
MaxClients         300
MinSpareThreads     25
MaxSpareThreads     75 
ThreadsPerChild     25
MaxRequestsPerChild  0
</IfModule>

KeepAlive Off
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100
KeepAliveTimeout 15
```

What can be the cause for the high CPU utilization for httpd in this case.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks
Sudhir

Answer (score 0):

I used to have two mysql servers that got pegged like this.  I would have a few scripts that did a few things.  One would tell me what the connection action was looking like (concurrrent session connections n the server) and log that.  The next thing would check the services usage and if the threshold reached 70% I would start killing connections and send myself some emails to see what was the deal.

It turned out that during your normal usage times when you would expect to see people browsing your site was borking my server).

Some of the things I did to mitigate this beside killing sessions (which is not cool).  Is to normalize my database, refactor tables that were seeing heavy usage.  I would then repair and reindex.

I also realized that certain things were beyond configuring.  We create redundancies.

I had to mirror my MySQL server and then route users based on request parameters.

Eventually I had realized that I need some better load balancing and ended up with 4 MySQL server and a load-balancer mitigating and directing traffic.

So your approach is on the query level and see what you can do there, then your DB/table refactoring and reindex.

Next create concurrent connection murder scripts and target users that are inactive and redirect them somewhere or just clip them and make way for the heavyweights on your site.

I did a lot of things over time but that is how it all started back in the day.

Hope this is helpful or at least gets you thinking about an approach